# What kind of SIMMs can 286 PCs use?

Tags: memory, 80286

I have a 286 Board (Octek Fox II 286) which takes up to four 30 pin SIMM modules. The manual however (http://www.minuszerodegrees.net/manuals/Octek%20-%20FOX-II%20286%20(12_16%20MHz%20versions).pdf) is silent about the speed of the RAM ICs.

So do I need 120ns SIMMs (hard to come by), or are 70 or 80ns ICs good, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

70 or 80ns SIMMs are supported, and are in fact required if you wish to run your system with no wait states. 120ns SIMMs would require one wait state. Even though your motherboard manual doesn’t mention memory speeds, the fact that is supports disabling wait states indicates that it works fine with faster memory. (AFAIK faster memory shouldn’t cause issues in any case.)

It appears that the Fox II uses a Headland HT12 chipset, and that chipset [is documented as supporting 0-wait-state operation at 16MHz with 80ns DRAM](http://www.vogonsdrivers.com/files/ht12a_user_manual.pdf).

You might find [this wait state calculator](https://www.matrix-bios.nl/calc/waitstates.html) useful.